# Agrupar dados por idades

Tags: postgresql

boas tenho uma base de dados que contem profissões , pessoas , e sexo

queria agrupar por faixa etaria e por profissao e sexo e fazer um calculo das mesma.

problema repete-me varias faixas por exemplo a profissao trolha tem 4 linhas do sexo F , com a mesma profissao e diferentes valores de contagem para a mesma faixa etaria.

```
  SELECT   SEXO.SEXO,
           PROFISSAO.PROFISSAO,
           COUNT (CASE WHEN DADOS.IDADE BETWEEN "0" AND "20" THEN "ate 20" END)
              AS FAIXAETARIA20,
           COUNT (
              CASE WHEN DADOS.IDADE BETWEEN "21" AND "50" THEN "de 21 a 50" END
           )
              AS FAIXAETARIA2250,
           COUNT (
              CASE WHEN DADOS.IDADE BETWEEN "51" AND "75" THEN "de 51 a 75" END
           )
              AS FAIXAETARIA51200
    FROM         DADOS
              LEFT JOIN
                 SEXO
              ON (DADOS.SEXO = SEXO.ID)
           LEFT JOIN
              PROFISSAO
           ON (DADOS.PROFISSAO = PROFISSAO.ID)
GROUP BY   PROFISSAO.PROFISSAO, SEXO.SEXO, DADOS.IDADE
```

Comment: Fazer um calculo das mesmas, que calculo? envolvendo o que?

Comment: Para agrupar do jeito que falou é so fazer `GROUP BY 3,2,1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colega.

Sua query está trazendo mais resultados porque você está agrupando pela `IDADE` também. Basta removê-la da query, agrupando assim somente pelo `SEXO` e `PROFISSAO`(GROUP BY).

Segue:

```
  SELECT   SEXO.SEXO,
           PROFISSAO.PROFISSAO,
           COUNT (CASE WHEN DADOS.IDADE BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN 'ate 20' END)
              AS FAIXAETARIA20,
           COUNT (
              CASE WHEN DADOS.IDADE BETWEEN 21 AND 50 THEN 'de 21 a 50' END
           )
              AS FAIXAETARIA2250,
           COUNT (
              CASE WHEN DADOS.IDADE BETWEEN 51 AND 75 THEN 'de 51 a 75' END
           )
              AS FAIXAETARIA51200
    FROM         DADOS
              LEFT JOIN
                 SEXO
              ON (DADOS.SEXO = SEXO.ID)
           LEFT JOIN
              PROFISSAO
           ON (DADOS.PROFISSAO = PROFISSAO.ID)
GROUP BY   PROFISSAO.PROFISSAO, SEXO.SEXO;
```